# Why does my array only print once and not twice here?

Tags: c++

```
int nums [] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};


int main(){
int size {10};

for (int i;i<size;i++)
    cout << nums[i] << " ";
    
for (int i;i<size;i++)
    cout << nums[i] << " ";

return 0;
}
```

This prints my array once but shouldn't I get my array printed twice not once?

Comment: You don't initialize `i` in those loops.

Comment: `i` is uninitialized, it could  be any value, including `>= size`. Use `for (int i = 0;...` instead.

Comment: In your own words, by writing `for (int i;i<size;i++)`, what do you expect should be the value of `i` before the loop starts? *Why*?

Comment: You shouldn't get anything from *this* program because it does not compile. Perhaps you are getting something wrong from some other, similar program? One that has necessary `#include` directives maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the `i` variable to the start index, like in `for (i = 0; i < size; i++)`. Otherwise `i` can start in any value and this is undefined behavior.